# A metric space that is no countable topological basis

Tags: general-topology

I know that a topology that if a topology is metrizable and separable, then it has a countable basis. Could someone give me an example of topology that is metrizable but has no countable basis ? Probably something like $L^\infty $ but I can't prove that it has no countable basis.

Comment: Discrete topology on uncountable sets maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $L^\infty[0,1]$ you can argue this way: For $t\in (0,1),$ define $f_t=\chi_{[0,t]}.$ Then if $0<s<t<1,$ $\|f_t-f_s\|_\infty=1.$ It follows that the open balls  $B(f_t,1/2),$ $t\in (0,1),$ in $L^\infty$ are pairwise disjoint. Thus any basis for $L^\infty$ is uncountable.

Comment: Hey ! Wonderful :) Congrat' (and thank you) for this wonderful example.

Comment: Just to be sure, if there is a countable basis, $\mathcal B=\{B_n\}$ then all $B(f_t,1/2)$ (that are disjoint) would contain at least $B_n$ and thus $\{B_n\}$ are not countable, right ?

Comment: would contain at least one $B_n,$ yes that's right

Answer (score 2):

A discrete space on uncountable set is metrizable (with a discrete metric). However, any singleton should belong to a basis.

Comment: What is a discrete space on uncountable set ? For me a discrete set is by definition countable.

Comment: Your intuition comes from probality theory. :-)

In topology a discrete space is a space, where any set is open. It is possible to gain by a discrete metric: $d(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$ and $d(x,y)=1$ otherwise.

Comment: Ok so nice proof :) I don't understand what you mean by "It is possible to gain by a discrete metric"

Comment: If you introduce a discrete metric, you arrive at a discrete topoogy.

Answer (score 0):

The plane in the jungle river metric is an example, as is $\ell^\infty$ (the sequence space), and the [hedgehog metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedgehog_space) with uncountably many spines.